# Products of differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let us consider $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\{x_i\}$ be a basis. Let $\{dx_i\}$ be the corresponding basis in the double dual. Do we assign meaning to the symbol $dx_idx_j$, and what does it mean? What do physicists mean when use such symbols?

Furthermore, let $c:I\to\mathbb R^n$ be a smooth line. Let $ds$ denote the line element along the line. What does the symbol $ds$ mean? If we assume $c=c(x)$ is an analytical parameterization of the line, how do we express $ds$ as a linear combination of the basis $\{dx_i\}$? How can we generalize this to higher dimensional surfaces?

(I am familiar with the exterior product of differential forms, and the differential geometry formalism.)

Comment: $dx_i\,dx_i$ is often a shorthand for $dx_i\wedge dx_j$, though is may also be (even more often) the symmetric product; $ds$ is a 1-form on $I$ and so you can't compare it with $dx_i$'s which are on $\mathbb R^n$; at best you can use $c^*dx_i$

Comment: $dx^idx^j$ can also denote a symmetric expression, as in $g_{ij}dx^idx^j$.

Comment: @user8268 By $c^*$ you mean the pullback of $c$, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physicists either use the notation $dx^idx^j$ to denote $dx^i\otimes dx^j$, or to denote $1/2\,(dx^i\otimes dx^j+dx^j\otimes dx^i)$. They are equal if contracted with a symmetric matrix, as in the metric tensor $g_{ij}dx^idx^j$.
Keep in mind that the exterior product, instead, is anti-symmetric: $dx^i\wedge dx^j= dx^i\otimes dx^j-dx^j\otimes dx^i$.

Let $c:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a parametrization. Then beware that $c(t)$, with $t\in \mathbb{R}$, is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $c(x)$ is *not* well defined!
$c(t)$ is a "vector", the argument of $c$ is simply a real parameter.

In this case, then:
$$
ds = \frac{dc}{dt}dt
$$

is the line element. That is, a 1-form *on $\mathbb{R}$* (not globally on $\mathbb{R}^n$). So, you cannot express $ds$ as a linear combination of the $dx^i$. It is linear in $dt$, though.

If you want it of unitary length, choose an affine parametrization, or (equivalently) divide $ds$ by its norm.

What *can* be a linear combination in the way you ask is *tangent vectors*. If $v$ is the tangent vector to the curve, then its components $v^i$ are exactly the coefficients of the linear combination $v^ie_i$, where the $e_i$ are the basis of vectors.
This reflects the fact that vectors "push forward", while differential forms "pull back". A map $M\to N$ can "push" vectors in $M$ to vectors in $N$, which will be linear combinations of the basis vectors of $N$.
For differential forms, instead, it's the opposite. Forms on $N$ can be "pulled back" to forms on $M$, just as we did above: $ds$ is the pull-back of the "length" form via the map $c$.

Just as well, if we have a surface $(u,v)\mapsto c(u,v)$, the surface element is:
$$
dA = \frac{\partial c}{\partial u}du\wedge \frac{\partial c}{\partial v}dv,
$$

which is a 2-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$, whose integral is the oriented area of the surface. And so on for higher-dimensional embedded manifolds.

Comment: The usual approach is to regard $ds$ as a density, not a form. This density makes sense on a manifold of any dimension, not just 1.